# Turn off HttpOnly for Flask Session for only one handler

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies, httponly

I'm using Flask defaults so that HttpOnly is set for the session cookie.

I have one handler for which I'd like to allow JavaScript to access the session cookie.

Is there a way to change the Flask session cookie for a single handler so that HttpOnly is false?

I tried this in my handler:

```
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = False
rsp = make_response(jsonify(...))
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
return rsp
```

but the cookie still had HTTPONLY set.  It looks like Flask adds the session cookie after making the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution using the info from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42289001/136598).

You can create the session cookie data like this:

```
from flask.sessions import SecureCookieSessionInterface
session_serializer = SecureCookieSessionInterface().get_signing_serializer(app)
session_clone = dict(foo='bar')
session_cookie_data = session_serializer.dumps(session_clone)
```

and you can then create your own cookie with the name session:

```
resp = make_response()
resp.set_cookie('session', session_cookie_data)
return resp
```